# ViewData.Model and ViewData.Eval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my Controller I have been setting

```
ViewData.Model = DBModel.Table.Take(1).Single();
```

Where DBModel is create by DBML file of Linq-to-SQL

And I can access the Value thro' `ViewData.Eval("ColumnName")`,

But If I create my own class

```
Class Test{

public string Col = "Testing ViewData";

}

Test objTest = new Test();

ViewData.Model = objTest;
```

Now If I try to get `ViewData.Eval("Col")` returns null.

Both I tried to store in ViewData.Model.

Whats the problem on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of *Col* is a field, not a property.  ViewData.Eval() only works against properties.

Answer (score 2):

The [**NerdDinner tutorial**](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) should give you a good feel for how this is all supposed to work.  `Eval` is not generally used in ASP.NET MVC.

The [**ViewData**](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm) section should be of particular interest to you.

Comment: `Eval` is not used directly but it is used internally within many of the html helpers.  `Html.DropDownList` for example will use `ViewData.Eval` to identify if a ViewData or Model property corresponds to the drop-down being created and it will automatically pre-select the right value.  The same is true for all editor generators.

Answer (score 0):

use `((Test)Model).Col` if your page does not implement `ViewPage<Test>`. Else use `Model.Col`

Comment: I have implement same for both the things

Comment: IMO you really should use strong view model